# How to find a host that is good for users in Egypt?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, networking

I currently have a site that's hosted in Texas. The majority of the users are from Egypt and I'm a bit concerned that the current hosting is not the optimal in terms of performance. The site is not slow but for how can I know if, for example, hosting it in Europe or Asia is better ?

Thanks in advance. I know this isn't a coding question per se....apologies if this is against any rules but..

Answer (score -1):

I'm recommending amazon ec2 (for dedicated virtual machines) or theplanet.com (for dedicated physical servers). scalability with ec2 is more easy and has multi datacenter support, also has cdn

Comment: thanks for the answer. but how can i tell if that will actually make a difference ? moving hosts is not something i want to do unless i am 100% sure it will actually make a considerable difference in performance.

Comment: you can guarantee it by using multiple datacenters

Comment: multiple datacenters do not really help when all customers are from one country. Then it would be better to chose a datacenter near to his customers.