# How to measure that a host is good for users in Egypt?

Tags: hosting, shared-hosting, networking

I currently have a site that's hosted in Texas.

The majority of my users are from Egypt and I'm a bit concerned that the current hosting is not the optimal in terms of performance. The site is not slow but for how can I know if, for example, hosting it in Europe or Asia is better ?

To clarify I need to know there is a way that I can test different hosting options - for example how can I test the average response time between Egypt and a host in Texas, the average response time between Egypt and a host in the UK ?

Comment: Can you rewrite this question please, it not very specific, what is your definition of better for instance, what type of server, what does it do - you've given us no real chance to answer well.

Comment: I've added more details, hope it's more clear now. cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a host that is good for users in Egypt ?](http://serverfault.com/questions/188324/how-to-find-a-host-that-is-good-for-users-in-egypt)

Answer (score 1):

You can test the performance with http://www.alertfox.com/Tools/LoadTime/ from different locations.

Answer (score 0):

you can ask for subjective opinions, you can ask someone there to use tools like [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [google's load time analyzer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3371/) but they will only provide you values [and maybe hints what to tweak] - it'll be up to you to decide if 1-2s of load time is good enough or not.

google and others have done lots of [studies](http://radar.oreilly.com/2009/06/bing-and-google-agree-slow-pag.html) and load time seems to be pretty crucial for the end-users.

depending on type of your site - you can consider moving it to European hosting [for dynamic content] and using CDN for moving static content closer to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

gomez and distributed testing networks can provide this

Answer (score 0):

There are several providers which will measure your performance externally (e.g. Pingdom).
You will need to find one with measure stations near your users.